# Get N lines from file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a master list of 100K records and each record belongs to a company number. I'm trying to create a sample data by selecting 2 of each company number. The "def Company" runs through the data and returns unique company number and counts per company number.

My script only outputs 2 records from the first company in the list and stops, how can I have the loop output 2 of each company?

Data looks like this(column[0] is the company number):

```
'54', '000054', '14571', '        0000010023'
'54', '000054', '14571', '        0000010033'
'4', '000054', '14571', '        0000010024'
'4', '000054', '14571', '        0000010023'
'433', '000054', '14571', '        000001023423'
'433', '000054', '14571', '        00000101563'
'433', '000054', '14571', '        00000100234523'
'433', '000054', '14571', '        00000100657823'
'433', '000054', '14571', '        0000010SDF023'
'78', '000054', '14571', '        000001002PIWEUR3'
'78', '000054', '14571', '        00000100J23'
'78', '000054', '14571', '        00000100222223'
'78', '000054', '14571', '        000001002445'
'12', '000054', '14571', '        0000010256'
'12', '000054', '14571', '        000001005666'




import os
import sys
import csv
from collections import Counter
masterlist = open('P:/20140408.txt', 'rb')
data = csv.reader(masterlist, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')

def Company():
    masterlist.seek(0)
    cnt = Counter()
    for row in data:
        cnt[row[0]] +=1

    return cnt


def maintest():
    companylist = Company().keys()
    masterlist.seek(0)
    s = 2


    for rows in data:
        if rows[0] in companylist and s > 0:
            print rows
            s -=1
maintest()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the stuff with counter, I would keep a simple mapping of company ID -> number of times seen as you walk through the loop:

```
seen = dict()
for row in data:
    n = seen.setdefault(row[0], 0)
    if n < 2:
        print row
    seen[row[0]] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a true 'sample' rather than the first two and if you can hold all the data in memory, you can do this:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from random import sample

data=defaultdict(list)

with open('/tmp/data.csv') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True, quotechar="'")
    for line in reader:
        data[line[0]].append(line[1:])

for k in data:
    print k, sample(data[k], 2)
```

With your sample data as the csv file, prints:

```
54 [['000054', '14571', '        0000010023'], ['000054', '14571', '        0000010033']]
12 [['000054', '14571', '        0000010256'], ['000054', '14571', '        000001005666']]
78 [['000054', '14571', '        000001002445'], ['000054', '14571', '        00000100J23']]
4 [['000054', '14571', '        0000010023'], ['000054', '14571', '        0000010024']]
433 [['000054', '14571', '        00000100234523'], ['000054', '14571', '        000001023423']]
```

Comment: Going to try this out with actual data as the files are about 800mb each.

Comment: 800 MB is not huge for most computers, but if your particular computer struggles you can just use enumerate on the csv file and then circle back and print those two random lines for each key.